# (Python) OpenCv: how do you create a left and right channel disparity maps respectively?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I can create a single channel depth map without issue with the CV2 library. However this creates a depth map from the mean of the left and right views, as if the image was taken from a 3rd camera in the middle stereoscopic cameras.

So basically I still want the depth/disparity map except I want it to be from the view of left and/or right input channel respectively. So I could have 2 output images from both angles

Sorry if I'm conflating terms here with the depth/disparity map.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

The disparity map is calculated having one of the images as being the reference, and the other is where you'll find the block matches and verify similarity and calculate distance (disparity).

Transforming it back to the other camera space is not possible because they do not even share the same field of view.

You have to repeat the same process, calculate the disparity map but now having the other camera being the reference.